# sort text file by groups of 2 lines

Tags: sorting, awk, sed

I have a file with the following structure:

```
A   35  74  dsadasd/1   0   +
A   95  74  dsadasd/2   0   -
B   75  159 dsadasd/2   0   +
B   78  852 dsadasd/1   0   -
C   12  789 dsadasd/1   0   +
C   91  546 dsadasd/2   0   -
A   87  52  dsadasd/2   0   +
A   52  15  dsadasd/1   0   -
```

I would like to sort it by the 4th field (which is basically sorting by the last number) in groups of two lines by two lines to output the following result:

```
A   35  74  dsadasd/1   0   +
A   95  74  dsadasd/2   0   -
B   78  852 dsadasd/1   0   -
B   75  159 dsadasd/2   0   +
C   12  789 dsadasd/1   0   +
C   91  546 dsadasd/2   0   -
A   52  15  dsadasd/1   0   - 
A   87  52  dsadasd/2   0   +
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there should be an easier way but this works

```
$ awk '{c+=p!=$1; p=$1; print c "\t" $0}' file | sort -k1,1 -k5 | cut -f2-

A   35  74  dsadasd/1   0   +
A   95  74  dsadasd/2   0   -
B   78  852 dsadasd/1   0   -
B   75  159 dsadasd/2   0   +
C   12  789 dsadasd/1   0   +
C   91  546 dsadasd/2   0   -
A   52  15  dsadasd/1   0   -
A   87  52  dsadasd/2   0   +
```

creates a group id based on the first field groups, sort by it first then the other key field; remove the dummy group id.

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk  '{
    k=NR%2; a[k]=$4; b[k]=$0                     # store compare value and 
}                                                #      record for 0 and 1
!(NR%2) {                                        # on even we compare
    print b[(a[0]>a[1])] ORS b[(a[0]<=a[1])]     # and print the smaller first
}' file
A   35  74  dsadasd/1   0   +
A   95  74  dsadasd/2   0   -
B   78  852 dsadasd/1   0   -
B   75  159 dsadasd/2   0   +
C   12  789 dsadasd/1   0   +
C   91  546 dsadasd/2   0   -
A   52  15  dsadasd/1   0   - 
A   87  52  dsadasd/2   0   +
```

Comment: Worked nicely, thanks also for expanding the explanation of commands!

Answer (score 1):

Try Perl.. note that this preserves the spaces in your input

```
 perl -0777 -ne ' while( /(.+?)\n(.+?)\n/gms ) { $a=$1;$b=$2; (split(/\s+/,$a))[3] gt (split(/\s+/,$b))[3] ? print "$b\n$a\n" : print "$a\n$b\n"  }'
```

with inputs

```
$ cat angel.txt
A   35  74  dsadasd/1   0   +
A   95  74  dsadasd/2   0   -
B   75  159 dsadasd/2   0   +
B   78  852 dsadasd/1   0   -
C   12  789 dsadasd/1   0   +
C   91  546 dsadasd/2   0   -
A   87  52  dsadasd/2   0   +
A   52  15  dsadasd/1   0   -

$ perl -0777 -ne ' while( /(.+?)\n(.+?)\n/gms ) { $a=$1;$b=$2; (split(/\s+/,$a))[3] gt (split(/\s+/,$b))[3] ? print "$b\n$a\n" : print "$a\n$b\n"  }' angel.txt
A   35  74  dsadasd/1   0   +
A   95  74  dsadasd/2   0   -
B   78  852 dsadasd/1   0   -
B   75  159 dsadasd/2   0   +
C   12  789 dsadasd/1   0   +
C   91  546 dsadasd/2   0   -
A   52  15  dsadasd/1   0   -
A   87  52  dsadasd/2   0   +

$
```

Comment: Works out nice! Thanks for the Perl example.

Answer (score 1):

awk + sort

```
$ awk ' { $(NF+1)=int((NR+1)/2) } 1 ' angel.txt | sort -k7,7 -k4,4 | awk  ' {$NF=""}1 '
A 35 74 dsadasd/1 0 +
A 95 74 dsadasd/2 0 -
B 78 852 dsadasd/1 0 -
B 75 159 dsadasd/2 0 +
C 12 789 dsadasd/1 0 +
C 91 546 dsadasd/2 0 -
A 52 15 dsadasd/1 0 -
A 87 52 dsadasd/2 0 +

$ cat angel.txt
A   35  74  dsadasd/1   0   +
A   95  74  dsadasd/2   0   -
B   75  159 dsadasd/2   0   +
B   78  852 dsadasd/1   0   -
C   12  789 dsadasd/1   0   +
C   91  546 dsadasd/2   0   -
A   87  52  dsadasd/2   0   +
A   52  15  dsadasd/1   0   -

$
```

Comment: Worked nice, only detail is I'm not sure why, but I get an extra line after each line with your command u.u

Answer (score 0):

This should work with `awk`:

```
awk '{if(p==""){p=$0;p4=$4} 
      else{
          if(p4>$4){print $0"\n"p}
          else{print p"\n"$0};p=p4=""
     }}' file
```

Comment: Almost, but the order of ../1 and ../2 is reversed. u.u

Comment: Ok. Changed that